# Worklight 7.1 Session Timeout in mobile FirstHybrid application

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am building a hybrid application , we are facing an issue with session in application we defined 1 minute session in **worklight.properties**
file and now after one minute if I tried to call adapter service it's still working so how can I maintain session in my application, as user is not logout. also after session out how logged in user will redirect to login page?

Here is my **worklight.properties** entry

serverSessionTimeout=1

my security realm defined below:

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<securityTests>

<mobileSecurityTest name="PushSecurityTest">
    <testAppAuthenticity />
    <testUser realm="AuthRealm" />
    <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
</mobileSecurityTest>

<customSecurityTest name="PushSecurityTestNew">
    <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" />
    <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" />
    <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" />
    <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" />
    <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" />
</customSecurityTest>

<customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
<test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
</customSecurityTest>

</securityTests>
<realms>    
<realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="AuthRealm">
<className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
<parameter name="login-function" value="PushAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
<parameter name="logout-function" value="PushAdapter.onLogout"/>
</realm>
<realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">

 <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>

</realm>
</realms>       


 <loginModules>
    <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="AuthLoginModule">
         <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>


  <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="-1">

  <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>

</loginModule>


 <loginModule name="rejectAll" expirationInSeconds="-1">

<className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>

</loginModule>


</loginModules>
```

**Query**

How session timeout will work and how user will redirect to login page after session timeout ?

Comment: In your **worklight.properties**, can you check the values of `mfp.session.independent` and `mfp.attrStore.type`?

Comment: @NathanH mfp.session.independent and mfp.attrStore.type properties not available in my worklight.properties.

Comment: Is your project using 7.1 from scratch, or did you import/upgrade from a previous version of MFP?

Comment: @NathanH it's 7.1 from scratch

Comment: Thanks - composing an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MobileFirst Platform 7.1 uses a mode called "session independent". This means that it does not use the concept of a session at all, and the value for `serverSessionTimeout` is no longer relevant.

Instead, the values you should look at are the `expirationInSeconds` for each of your `loginModule`. Each Login Module can have its own expiration time. Try a value of 60 seconds and see how it affects your flow.

Regarding "how user will redirect to login page", this is all done through your challenge handler. When a request will be sent to a protected adapter, and the login module expired, you will receive the same challenge that was sent for the first request.

It is up to you, in code, to catch the challenge (with a challenge handler) and display the correct login prompt to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i tried your above solution by giving expirationInSeconds in loginmodules but still i am able to invoke adapter from device.

Comment: What about the first time you request, do you get the login prompt?

Comment: Yes on application start we get login prompt.

Comment: Which security test is your adapter protected by?

Comment: Also if you have a simple project to share with us maybe I can try to run it myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96127/discussion-between-priyank-and-nathan-h).

Comment: Is there any luck @Priyank

Comment: @user1653871 go to the chat above. I did not get any updates since.